# copyFileSync not copying file and not throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm running a function which I've written in JavaScript inside a nodejs/Electron client.

This function is meant to copy a file from the users flash drive to their `c:/Windows/System32` (The file is being copied there so that it can be ran from Command Prompt manually next time the computer is touched without having to switch directories)

The problem is, the files are not being copied, and copyFileSync is not throwing an error.

Here is the code I'm specifically having a problem with:

```
try {
    console.log('copying t.bat');
    fs.copyFileSync(remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\files\\t.bat', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\t.bat');
} catch(err) {

    console.log('could not copy t.bat', err);

    $('#mfail_title').text('Could not copy t.bat file');
    $('#mfail_data').text(err);

    UIkit.modal("#master_fail").show();

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, I have `copyFileSync` inside a `TRY CATCH` block. I know this code is running because in the console I get `copying t.bat`, but nothing else.

How can I get my files to copy, or at least throw an error when it cannot?

This client is running inside OOBE mode on various Windows 10 machines, therefore always has administrator access.

---

I've tried updating to the async version of copyFile, but I'm having the same issue. Here is my code

```
var source = remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\files\\t.bat';
var destination = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\t.bat';

fs.copyFile(source, destination, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        source = remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\files\\p.bat';
        destination = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\p.bat';

        fs.copyFile(source, destination, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {

                source = remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\files\\p.bat';
                destination = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\p.bat';

                child = spawn("powershell.exe",['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-File', remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\' + type + '.ps1']);

            }
        });

    }
});
```

This should copy a file, then when it's complete it should copy another file, once that is complete, it should run a powershell script.

Each copyFile checks for an error before moving on, but it never throws an error, and the file is never copied.

Comment: can u log this remote.app.getAppPath() as well or use __dirname

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh The paths I am getting are correct. `E:\~REDACTED~\resources\app\app\files\scripts\files\t.bat` (Using `remote.app.getAppPath() + '\\app\\files\\scripts\\files\\t.bat'`) I've verified and this IS the location of the file. `__dirname` gives me `E:\~REDACTED~\resources\app\app`

Comment: can you use the async version and check if there is an error? or it is working?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty How can I ensure the files were copied if I use the async version? These files MUST be copied before moving onto the next part of the script. (The next part of the script shuts down the computer)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton just stick the next part in the callback function?

Comment: @pushkin I'll give this a try.

Comment: @pushkin I switched to copyFile, and I'm getting the same issue. Will update my question

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue earlier, In which an **Antivirus**(Comodo) was not allowing electron app to access the hard drive.

Copy and other file operations were successful in that case as well, because electron in such case access the corresponding **sandbox**

Please check this is not the case with you.

You can actually access 'fs' in console from electron and check other things in the file system.

Comment: I don't think this is the case here, because I don't think there is an anti virus running in OOBE mode. Even if there was, my application has administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if you're using fs on then renderer process (client side) which will not work (assuming that your fs is the node.js fs module and (*)). Your first script seems to use jQuery (hints for renderer) and the second one uses remote in the first line.

fs can only (*) be used on the main process and you'll need to create an IRC channel and do something like:

```
ircRenderer.sendSync('copy-file-sync', {from: '/from/path', to: '/to/path'})
```

and, of course, implement the handler for that quickly invented 'copy-file' channel on the main process.

(*) Edit: I haven't played around a lot with `nodeIntegration = true`, so fs may or may not work on the renderer process with that flag set on the BrowserWindow. But the irc messaging should definitely work and if not, the problem is outside electron, probably related to file permissions.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger this from the renderer process? I only want to copy the files when the user does an action, and there are other certain criteria that must be met which is all set up in the client.

Comment: fs works on the client side when `nodeintegration: true`

Comment: I also don't understand why it isn't throwing an error if the file isn't copied?